# WP7 - Delete multiple items Linq to XML

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, linq-to-xml

I need to delete all items from my XML file where node `Finished != ""` but my code delete only first item where this condition is true

My code:

```
try
{
    var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    XElement xElem;

    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream read = file.OpenFile("tasks.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        xElem = XElement.Load(read);
    }

    var tasks = from task in xElem.Elements("Task")
                where (string)task.Element("Finished") != ""
                select task;

    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream write = file.CreateFile("tasks.xml"))
    {
        foreach (XElement task in tasks)
        {
            task.Remove();
        }

        xElem.Save(write);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

But if I replace `task.Remove();` by `MessageBox` it shows me message box multiple times as it is right.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You should call `ToList()` when you search for items and then use that list as a source in `foreach` loop, instead of `IEnumerable`.

```
var tasks = (from task in xElem.Elements("Task")
             where (string)task.Element("Finished") != ""
             select task).ToList();
```

It's described on MSDN, within [`XNode.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) method description:

> In LINQ to XML programming, you should not manipulate or modify a set
>   of nodes while you are querying for nodes in that set. In practical
>   terms, this means that **you should not iterate over a set of nodes and
>   remove them**. Instead, you should materialize them into a List by
>   using the ToList extension method. Then, you can iterate over
>   the list to remove the nodes. For more information, see Mixed
>   Declarative Code/Imperative Code Bugs (C#) (LINQ to XML).